# Exception calling GetCurrentPositionAsync on Android using Task.Run

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, geolocation

I'm trying to get the device location using CrossGeolocator in Xamarin Forms on Android, but the following code throws an Exception with the message "Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()". How can I call GetPositionAsync without blocking the UI Thread?

**Locator Service**

```
public async Task<Position> GetCurrentLocation(double desiredAccuracy = 100)
{
  Position position = null;
  try
  {
    var locator = CrossGeolocator.Current;
    locator.DesiredAccuracy = desiredAccuracy;

    var available = await locator.GetIsGeolocationAvailableAsync();
    var enabled = await locator.GetIsGeolocationEnabledAsync();
    if (!available || !enabled)
    {
      throw new Exception("Location Error.");
    }

    position = await locator.GetPositionAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20), null, true);
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
    {
      App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Location Error", ex.Message, "Ok");
    });
  }

  return position;
}
```

**Page.xaml.cs**

```
private ILocationService _location;
private UserAccountViewModel _vm;
public UserAccountPage(UserAccountViewModel viewModel)
{
  InitializeComponent();
  BindingContext =_vm = viewModel;

  var _location = App.Container.Resolve<ILocationService>();

  Task.Run(async () => await _location.GetCurrentLocation())
    .ContinueWith(r =>
    {
      var loc = r.Result;
      _vm.UserAccount.Latitude= loc?.Latitude;
   }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
}
```

If I call _location.GetCurrentLocation() outside of Task.Run, it returns the correct value, but then I can't update the UI.

**Edit/Update:**
I can also call the following code from the page constructor without any exception, so the issue has to be with Xam.Plugin.Geolocator, I just can't find any information on this scenario...

```
var dataService = App.Container.Resolve<IDataService>();
Task.Run(async () => await dataService.UserAccount.Localisations())
  .ContinueWith(result =>
  {
    _vm.UserAccount.FirstName = result.Result.Count().ToString();
  }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

**Workaround:** I moved the code to the ViewModel and removed Task.Run, then just called the function from the page constructor, but I would still like to know how to call this code using Task.

```
public async Task UpdateLocation()
{
  var _location = App.Container.Resolve<ILocationService>();
  var loc = await _location.GetCurrentLocation();
  UserAccount.Latitude = loc?.Latitude;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write that code in **OnAppearing** method. Like,

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
  var _location = App.Container.Resolve<ILocationService>();

  Task.Run(async () => await _location.GetCurrentLocation())
  .ContinueWith(r =>
   {
      var loc = r.Result;
      _vm.UserAccount.Latitude= loc?.Latitude;
   }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
}
```

Comment: This gives the same  "Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()" error.